# Proof for a ring being right Artinian but not left Artinian

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I am currently looking at the following example (and other similar examples) and I can follow the proof that it is a right Artinian ring and I also follow the example given as to why it is not a left Artinian ring.

However,  I do not understand what is stopping us from applying the reasoning used to show it is right Artinian to conclude that it is also left Artinian. I do not see which bit of the proof fails and was wondering if anyone could help?
I have also attached the statements of the theorems used in the proof.

[image: question]

[image: theorem]

[image: another theorem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence in the second paragraph fails to be true when you consider the left module structure.
As a right $R$-module, $J$ does not contain any submodules except for $0$ and $J$.
However, as a left $R$-module $J$ contains an infinite descending chain of submodules.

To see this, note that the right $R$-module structure on $J$ is essentially the $\mathbb Q(x)$-module structure on $\mathbb Q(x)$. However, if you multiply $J$ with $R$ from the left, you get the $\mathbb Q$-module structure on $\mathbb Q(x)$. Now, as $\mathbb Q(x)$-module, $\mathbb Q(x)$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space, i.e., simple. However as a $\mathbb Q$-module, $\mathbb Q(x)$ is infinite-dimensional, hence not Artinian.

The same reasoning works, for instance, for the ring $\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb Z & \mathbb Q \\ 0 & \mathbb Q \end{pmatrix}$: ${}_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ is not Artinian, but $\mathbb Q_{\mathbb Q}$ is.

Comment: I thought this may be the case, but now thanks to your answer I understand why it is so!

Comment: Glad to be of help.